# passing function as props generates an error in React Native(onPress is not a function, 'onPress' is an instance of Object)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-props

I'm trying to trigger some action in parent component from child component and I'm using props for that. One of the props of the child is a function which updates parent's state when a button is pressed, which should cause parent to re-render but that's not the case, instead I get this error: `TypeError: onPress is not a function. (In 'onPress(event)', 'onPress' is an instance of Object)`. I've used function as props and updated the state several times in React but in React Native I don't seem to understand what's causing this issue and how I can solve it from information I've found online.

Child component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph } from 'react-native-paper';

const Photo:React.FC<{url:string, camera:string, handleClick:()=>void}> = ({url, camera}:{url:string, camera:string}, handleClick:()=>void) => (
  <Card >
    <Card.Content >
      <Paragraph style={{color:'#6200ee'}}>{camera}</Paragraph>
    </Card.Content>
    <Card.Cover source={{ uri: url }} />
    <Card.Actions>
      <Button onPress={handleClick} mode='contained'>more</Button>
    </Card.Actions>
  </Card>
);

export default Photo;
```

Parent Component:

```
 import React, {useContext, useEffect, forwardRef, useState, Ref, useImperativeHandle, useRef} from 'react'
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native-paper';
import {theContext}  from '../utils/ContextPlaceholder'
import getPhotos from '../utils/getPhotos'
import Photo from './Photo'
import axios from 'axios';
import {PhotosViewV2} from './PhotosViewV2'
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

interface RefObject {
    getData: () => void
  }



export const PhotosView = forwardRef((props, ref: Ref<RefObject>)=> {
    const [photos, setPhotos]=useState<any[]>([])
    const[clicked, setClicked]=useState(false)
    const context=useContext(theContext)
    const{rover, camera, year,month,day} =context
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({getData}));
    async function getData() {
      const photos=await getPhotos(1,rover, camera, year,month,day)
      setPhotos(photos)
    }
    return(
        <View>
        <ScrollView>
          {photos.map(({cam, url},idx)=>{
            return <Photo handleClick={()=>setClicked(true)} camera={cam} key={idx} url={url}/>
          })}
          
        </ScrollView>
        <PhotosViewV2 clickedFromOutside={clicked} data={photos}/>
        </View>
        );
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here `({url, camera}:{url:string, camera:string}, handleClick:()=>void)` You get `url` and `camera` from the first parameter, which is `props`, and `handleClick` from the second, which is `forwardRef`, which is indeed an object. You need to re-write it like this:

```
({url, camera, handleClick}:{url:string, camera:string, handleClick:()=>void})
```

Comment: Wow, how could I not notice this, thanks!